# linear operator on a vector space V such that $T^2 -T +I=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

let T be a linear operator on a vector space V such that $T^2 -T +I=0$.Then

1. T is oneone but not onto.
2. T is onto but not one one.
3. T is invertible.
4. no such T exists.

could any one give me just hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at a problem similar to this, and these answers are great but I needed a bit more to make it click. Here is a step by step with the rules used.

$T^2 − T + I = 0$

$TT = T - I$

$TT = T - TT^{-1}$ *, because* $I = TT^{-1}$

$TT = IT - TT^{-1}$ *, because* $IT = T$

$TT = T(I-T^{-1})$ *, factor out the T*

$T = I - T^{-1}$ *, remove T from both sides*

In my case we had to prove $T^{-1} = 2I - T$ given almost the same equation (that 2 being the difference). I know this break down is probably too basic for most, but this what helped me understand how to apply those rules.

I was lead here by [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538731/if-a2-is-a-matrix-such-that-a2-a-i-0-show-that-a-is-invertible-wit).

Answer (score 6):

$$
T^2-T+I=0 \iff T(I-T)=I=(I-T)T,
$$
i.e. $T$ is invertible and $T^{-1}=I-T$. In particular $T$ is injective and surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{x}$ be any vector in the nullspace. Then $T\mathbb{x} = \mathbb{0}$. Using your equation $T^2 - T + I = 0$, what can you conclude about $\mathbb{x}$?

Alternatively if you know about minimal polynomials: How does your polynomial split?

Comment: $T^2(x)-T(x)=0$ and so $I(x)=0$ so $x=0$ so $T$ is injective. am I right?

Comment: I know about minimal polynomial, it has distinct roots over the field $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Your mapping is injective. It is not necessarily surjective unless $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: It is surjective: $T(-Tx + x) = x$

Comment: Oh, well that's that. Thank you for catching my mistake @RobertIsrael

Comment: To settle the existence (question 4) you may study the rotation of the real plane by 60 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

$T(T-1)= -I$ then $\det T\cdot \det (T-I) = (-1)^n$ which implies $\det (T) \neq0 \,\,.$ hence $T$ invertible

Comment: Is it true for a vector space with not a finit dimension ?